# Returned value arent valid did it run out of gas?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

After migration command line (truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby), it is deploy. However i couldnt see at etherscan website when i enter the contract address. Should i see? Whatever then i write these comman lines respectively.

```
  truffle console
  Election.deployed().then(function(instance) { app = instance })
  app.address
```

These are fine but after this command it gives error.

```
  app.candidate()
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is your contract address?

Comment: @ Ismael Migration contract address: 0xF6FA28D8dEE5A924912B13C4b162A634e255A653
Election contract address:  0xe420129E2Aa335C67Eb1e303C5D63B4BaE4802be

Comment: Searching in rinkeby.etherscan.io those addresses are empty which means the deployment has failed. What was the output from `truffle migrate`? Do you have enough funds in your wallet?

Comment: @Ismael and also output was saving migrations to chain and saving artifacts. Does it mean to deploy to rinkeby?

Comment: @Ismael when i write this command eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase) it returns 7.9228162734264337593543950335e+28

Comment: That is very large amount, 1 ether is 1e+18. Are you deploying to rinkeby or a private network?

Comment: @Ismael i try to deploy rinkeby test environment. I am using geth

Comment: I though you were using rinkeby from the commandline. Without a way to reproduce your problem it is impossible to determine what went wrong.